# Create Custom annotation which declares and initiates a Object

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create an annotation, which will be Target *TYPE* and declare an object of a custom class.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Test {
}

class Student{

}
```

**Perform**

```
@Test
class example{
    //Want this annotation to declare something like this
    Student s = new Student();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want that? You could technically (with much difficulty) make it happen, but it would be quite useless.

Comment: I want to achieve something like @Slf4j, which declares an log object

Comment: Then you have an example to look at. See how the annotations processing and code generation is done for `@Slf4j` and learn from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create CGLIB proxy which extends classes annotated with `@Test` and you can add the property to the proxy. But I don't think it will serve any purpose. Here is the sample code which you use for the starter.

First get list of classes annotated with `Test`

```
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections ("com.demo");
    Set<Class<?>> testClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Test.class);
```

Then create a proxy of these classes using `CGLIB` and add student property to it.

```
for (Class<?> test : testClasses) {
    BeanGenerator beanGenerator = new BeanGenerator ();
    beanGenerator.setSuperclass (test);
    beanGenerator.addProperty("student", Student.class);
    Object myBean = (test) beanGenerator.create();  
    Method setter = myBean.getClass().getMethod("setStudent", Student.class);
    setter.invoke(myBean, new Student()); 
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is generally not supported by the annotation processor specification, AFAIK. An annotated class must not manipulate its own [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

[Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) (which provides the mentioned [@Slf4j](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/slf4j/Slf4j.html) annotation) seems to have found some unsupported hook, which actually makes it a hack.

If you still want to do something similar I suggest to have a look at the [Lombok source code](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok).

**Update:**

I just found a [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-custom-annotation) which explains how to implement a custom Lombok annotation (I haven't read it yet, though). So maybe you can build something on top of Lombok, if you want to.

Comment: Maybe create CGLIB proxy and add properties at runtime via reflection?